# Shift between MDI child forms

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, mdichild

I have a MDI form, and I want to be able to shift between the child forms.
Is there any method to do this?

I know there I can use CTRL+F6 to achieve this, and I could simulate those keys; but I would like an easy solution.

Comment: the mdi parent contains a list of mdi children as "this.MdiChildren". if you can access this from the child, get the instance of the child you want and then BringToFront() ?

Comment: @andrew thanks, but I just found the answer. Cant post it yet because I dont have 100 reputation =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completely forgot to add the answer, but here it is:

```cs
this.SelectNextControl(this.ActiveControl, true, true, true, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:
`this.MdiChildren[i].BringToFront()`
where `i` is the index of the form you want to bring to front (they are sorted by first one to open is the first, second is the second etc)

btw,
ctrl+tab is easier then ctrl+F6... 
(works in almost any windows tab based program (f.e. chrome), unlike ctrl+f6)